# Calling a function by an interval in a function called by interval JS

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to call a function that could check an amount of time constantly using an interval within function that already works (running function) by interval.
That what I had did:

```
 var interval;
 var time = prompt("Insert amount of time in seconds");
 function log ()
 {
 console.log ("log() called.");
 }
 function onrunning ()
 {
  interval = setInterval(log,time*1000);
}
gameloop = setInterval(onrunning,5);//This interval must not cleared
```

The first amount of time works fine but after that it's keep calling the log() function faster and faster till the browser crashes.
I tried to do this

```
var interval;
var time = prompt("Insert amount of time in seconds");
function log ()
{
console.log ("log() called.");
}
function onrunning ()
 {
  interval = setInterval(log,time*1000);
 }
 gameloop = setInterval(onrunning,5);
 clearInterval(interval); //tried this but no differece.
```

Comment: `setInterval` - calls the callback multiple times, `setTimeout` calls the callback once - not sure if that help

Comment: Where exactly did you call ``clearInterval(interval)``? Could you include it in your complete code?

Comment: I guess you want to execute `log` just a given amount of times (given in prompt), then stop logging, right? Or just once after the prompted time will be past?

Comment: keep logging every given time, it shouldn't stop,, but it's do the first log in the time, but after it the log function keep being called faster and faster till the browser crashes. @Teemu

Comment: Looks like `case "a"` will pass very often in `onrunning`. And when it's run on every 5 msecs, you will quickly get a ton of new log intervals. Also I think Jaromanda X has (at least a partial) solution to your problem in their comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing interval in a wrong place.

In your code, you are trying to clear it **before** it has been created (so it's basically a no-op).

You want to clear it **after** it has been created **and** executed:

```
function log ()
{
    console.log ("log() called.");
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

You should also notice that since your `onrunning` is also fired as an "interval" callback, you are creating new log intervals on each callback execution frame. If you want to clear this interval too, just replicate the same logic as presented above, but inside `onrunning` callback.

---

I assume you want to fire the "log" callback ("onrunning" callback as well, probably) only once after a set period of time. In that case, you should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

This has been already pointed out by **Jaromanda X** [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366380/calling-a-function-by-an-interval-in-a-function-called-by-interval-js?noredirect=1#comment66061213_39366380).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.
I have did something like that but it's still call log() function faster and faster.
All I want is to call the log() function in amount of time constantly.
`   var timeout1;
    var time = prompt("Insert amount of time in seconds");
    function log ()
    {
    console.log ("log() called.");
    clearTimeout(timeout1);
    }
    function onrunning ()
     {
      timeout1 = setTimeout(log,time*1000);
      }

     gameloop = setInterval(onrunning,5);`

Comment: In that case, you should clear the ``onrunning`` interval, not the ``log`` interval. As I've already told, just replicate the same logic as with clearing ``log`` interval.